# Format exception thrown

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, checkbox, ado.net

I have gridview which is loaded on basis of date range that i provide in textboxes. It work fines but it throws FORMAT EXCEPTION ERROR when i ENter data range for which no record exists in Database. it Throws error on line where i have binded Checkbox to database column.

Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"    Width="550px" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />    
        <%-- <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" /> --%>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FromMobileNo" DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Message" DataField="Message" >     
            <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsComplaint">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsComplaint").ToString()) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchSmsComplaintsByDate_SP]
    @DateFrom Datetime = null,
    @DateTo DateTime = null
AS
BEGIN
    Begin Try
        IF(@DateFrom is null AND @DateTo is null)
        Begin
            Set @DateFrom = Convert(date,(Select min(ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime) from ReceivedMessages))
            Set @DateTo = Convert(date,(Select max(ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime) from ReceivedMessages))

            SELECT [ID]
            ,REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 106), ' ','/') as RecievingDate
            ,[FromMobileNo]
            ,[Message]
            ,[IsComplaint]
            FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
            where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo
            AND IsComplaint!=1

        End
        Else IF(@DateFrom is not null AND @DateTo is not null)
        Begin
            SELECT [ID]
            ,REPLACE(convert(varchar, ReceivedMessages.ReceivedDateTime, 106), ' ','/') as RecievingDate
            ,[FromMobileNo]
            ,[Message]
            ,[IsComplaint]
            FROM [CmsSMSDb].[dbo].[ReceivedMessages] 
            where Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)>= @DateFrom AND Convert(date,ReceivedDateTime)<= @DateTo 
            AND IsComplaint!=1
        End
    End Try
    Begin Catch
         Select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMsg
    End Catch
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem likely stems from this line;

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsComplaint").ToString()) %>' />
```

If the data for the `IsComplaint` field is null / empty, then the conversion to a boolean will fail with a format exception.

You can add a row databound event to your gridview to give you finer control over the data conversion.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid"
    BorderColor="#333333" Width="550px"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging"
    OnRowDataBound="GridViewSmsComplaints_RowDataBound" >
```

... and include something similar to the following in your code-behind file

```
protected void GridViewSmsComplaints_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        CheckBox ckboxIsComplaint = e.Row.FindControl("ckboxIsComplaint") as CheckBox;

        if (ckboxIsComplaint != null) {
            bool isComplaint;
            string dataItem = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsComplaint") as string;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataItem)) {
                if (Boolean.TryParse(dataItem, out isComplaint)) {
                    ckboxIsComplaint.Checked = isComplaint;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then remove the inline-databinding from the checkbox component (as this is now handled in the code-behind). So it just becomes a plain checkbox control;

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint" runat="server" />
```